# Get text in current line when some previous lines was collapsed in my own eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, text-editor

Im trying to get the text beginning of the current line to the mouse cursor.

```
ITextSelection textSelection= (ITextSelection) textEditor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
IRegion lineInfo = null;
int offsetCurrentCursor = textSelection.getOffset();
int offsetLine; // THIS IS THE VALUE THAT I WANT
try {
    int lineNumber = document.getLineOfOffset(offsetCurrentCursor);
    lineInfo = document.getLineInformation(lineNumber);
    offsetLine = lineInfo.getOffset();
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
}

StyledText styledText = (StyledText) textEditor.getAdapter(Control.class);
String currentText = "";
if (offsetLine <= offsetCurrentCursor - 1) {
    currentText = styledText.getText(offsetLine, offsetCurrentCursor - 1);
}
```

But the method `getText` of `StyledText` doesn't work when some previous lines are collapsed.

Another problem is that Im trying to move the cursor using `StyledText.setCaretOffset(int offset)` and it also doesn't work when some previous lines are collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IDocument`

```
public String get(int offset, int length)
```

method to get the text.

To get from a model (document) offset to the StyledText offset AbstractTextViewer uses:

```
protected static int modelOffset2WidgetOffset(ISourceViewer viewer, int modelOffset) {
    if (viewer instanceof ITextViewerExtension5) {
        ITextViewerExtension5 extension = (ITextViewerExtension5) viewer;
        return extension.modelOffset2WidgetOffset(modelOffset);
    }
    return modelOffset - viewer.getVisibleRegion().getOffset();
}
```

To use this you need access to the text editor `ISourceViewer`.

Comment: It works, but now I have another problem with StyledText. I move the cursor using StyledText.setCaretOffset(int offset) and now its not moved to correctly position. I can do it with IDocument? Thanks a lot. I looked at documentation api of IDocument but not found anything.